# MapR hive is not detecting maprfs:/// scheme, showing invalid URL error

Tags: hadoop, hive, mapr

I'm using mapR Hive 1.2 with Hadoop 2.7.0. When trying to run following command :

```
add jar maprfs:///user/john/customSerde.jar
```

I get the following error :

```
invalid url: maprfs:///user/john/customSerde.jar, expecting ( file | hdfs | ivy)  as url scheme. 
Query returned non-zero code: 1, cause: invalid url: maprfs:///user/john/customSerde.jar, expecting ( file | hdfs | ivy)  as url scheme.
```

It simply can't detect the maprfs:/// scheme. However the same command works fine in mapR hive 0.13. Can anyone help please.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug.

The workaround is to use `hdfs://` instead of the traditional `maprfs://`

Comment: The fix for this bug has been committed to MapR's Hive binary

https://github.com/mapr/hive/commit/ecc94f7d9c7b68ce79363026b5648bab8ecfb92f